# Running a batch file as a scheduled task does not behave as it should?

Tags: java, mysql, windows, batch-file, jdbc

I have a jar file, which uses jdbc to connect to a sql db and add a new record. To execute this with an arg I put the cmd line command in a batch file to run it.

Now if I manually click and run the batch file it works fine and I can see the new record in my sql database, but I have created a scheduled task to run the batch file for me once day which it seems do successfully but there are no new records added to the database.

Any ideas on why this happens?

The batch file is just one line, as it seemed to work when I ran it? :

> java -Dvar=daily -jar SQL_JDBC_Bandon.jar

Comment: post the batch please ... Did you try to find out if the batch is executed at all ? add something like "echo HereIAm! >> C:\temp\batch.log". With which credentials do you run the batch ? Do you pass parameters (they easily get lost) ? Perhaps the user used in this context is not allowed to do something ...

Comment: The batch works if I just click and run it, and the task history says the task ran successfully?

Comment: The task history can be wrong ... Please post some more details because without details we can only guess.

Comment: Nope. This did not work. All the log file shows is: JDBC executed 17/06/2015 12:25:00.52

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Comment: @Marged Yes see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a while back, but all I did was put these 2 lines in a .bat file and it works without any issues as a scheduled task:

```
cd C:\Users\SQLService\Desktop\ScadaCalcs
java -Dvar=daily -jar SQL_JDBC_Bandon.jar
```

One thing to note is that the jar and script are both in the ScadaCalcs directory, but I had to cd an absolute path for it to work.

Comment: so how is this different from the two lines "C:" / "CD" from my answer ?

Comment: Different because your way didn't work for whatever reason. It would execute but not actually do what it was supposed to.

Comment: Splitting this into two separate lines / commands yields the same result, so the mistake must have been somewhere else. Cd'ing the way you do carries a risk depending on where you start the batch file

Comment: What kind of risks should I be aware of? the batch starts from a folder on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

I post this as an answer because it would look ugly in a comment.

To have a log of executions to compare to the task execution log of scheduled tasks create a batch similar to this.

```
@echo off
echo JDBC executed %DATE% %TIME% >> C:\temp\logs\jdbctask.log
C:
cd \PathToYourJar
C:\Programs\Java\bin\java -version >> C:\temp\logs\jdbctask.log
Dir C:\Programs\Java\bin\java.* >> C:\temp\logs\jdbctask.log
C:\Programs\Java\bin\java -Dvar=daily -jar SQL_JDBC_Bandon.jar >> C:\temp\logs\jdbctask.log
```

This makes sure that you don't rely on PATH or JAVA_HOME variables that might not be set for the user you run the batch in. Please adjust the paths to your needs.
If this still fails, post the results of the log file.

Comment: Ok I will give this a try. Is there a reason why it works when running manually vs as a schedualed task?

Comment: as a scheduled task it runs in another context - with another "homedirectory", so probably it can't find your files.

Comment: Nope. This did not work. All the log file shows is: JDBC executed 17/06/2015 12:25:00.52

Comment: @ruffles I assume you adjusted the paths according to your environment ? I made another edit to the batch